# sed is not working to replace string in another bash function?

Tags: regex, bash, shell, awk, sed

I have a simple bash script test.sh like:

```
#!/bin/bash
test_1_2_3_321
function setup {
    DEFAULT_TEST_ROOT=/
    test_1_2_3_321
}
```

I used the sed command as:

```
sed -ri 's/^test_[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]{3}$/test_1_2_3_444/' ./test.sh
```

After the sed, the content of the bash is:

```
#!/bin/bash
test_1_2_3_444
function setup {
    DEFAULT_TEST_ROOT=/
    test_1_2_3_321
}
```

As you can see, only the first line is updated, the "test_1_2_3_321" in function "setup" is not changed at all, why? How can I make the sed working for both?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Tried, still only works for the 1st one as before. sed -ri 's/^test_[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]_[0-9]{3}$/test_1_2_3_444/g' ./test.sh

Comment: It only works if the 3 digits are at the end of the string. Haven't you got any trailing space inside the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because your regex doesn't match the line.  The `^` anchor requires the match to be at beginning of line.  If that's not what you mean, don't say that.

As an aside, modifying your executables is usually a bad idea. The standard way to achieve something like this is to pass the variable part to the script as a parameter.

```
#!/bin/bash
"$1"
function setup {
    DEFAULT_TEST_ROOT=/
    "$1"
}
```

Invoke it like `./yourscript test_1_2_3_321` to run it with `test_ 1_2_3_321` as the value.

Comment: Exactly. Now I understand this command better. Thanks so much.